# Nvidia dGPU constantly crashing on Asus X550VX when switching to Intel HD 630 integrated one

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics

Got this new laptop few days ago. Installed everything nicely (screw you MS and that shady tactic of increasing W10 market share forcibly though) but I'm getting "The Nvidia Geforce GTX 950M device is not removable and cannot be ejected or unplugged.", mostly when I switch from something that uses dGPU to the desktop (which uses integrated). After that, GTX950M disappears from device manager and unknown 3D accelerator which fails to install appears. Nothing can be done about this unless I reboot. Then it appears, and crashes again and so on. I've tried these common things about preferences and power management and nothing seems to help. Can't really turn off integrated one either. I'm at my wits end. How can I fix this?

Model: ASUS X550VX-DM561/X550VXK (Laptop)
GPU: GTX950M, no overclock
CPU: [Intel Core i5 7300HQ](https://ark.intel.com/products/97456/Intel-Core-i5-7300HQ-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_50-GHz) (with Intel(R) HD Graphics 630), no overclock
Motherboard: Aida64 doesn't seem to know, bios is latest
RAM: 8Gb @ 2400
Operating System & Version: Win 7 with SP1 x64, clean install with all updates
GPU Drivers: 388.13 (Latest for Nvidia) + 21.20.16.48 for integrated one (last installable drivers without .inf modifications, downloaded from [MS update catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=12902d74-fd67-4a92-9245-57271b47b41f)/[.cab](http://download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/driver/drvs/2016/11/20958792_e88fb739e1def2aa698bb33461618b51bb32eb80.cab))

Comment: This laptop does not support Windows 7.

Comment: @LittleHelper totally does though. Drivers are available. Everything works fine, except this GPU problem

Comment: Is this it https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/X550VX/ ?

Comment: @LittleHelper yes

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't support Windows 7. Just because you managed to install drivers, doesn't mean everything will work.

Comment: @LittleHelper just because their website says "Asus recommends win 10" and their download list only gives win 10 as an option, doesn't mean it won't work. Hardware totally supports win 7 and official drivers for it are provided. Besides, problem is not unique to win 7, people had similar problems with other gpus on Win 10 as well.

Comment: The drivers most likely are for other sub-versions of this laptop that may support Windows 7 (this does happen - where you can install drivers which are technically for other yet very similar products, and I have personally abused this myself). In the `Specifications` tab under `Operating System` the one and only operating system listed is Windows 10. Yes, it is forced on us, but in the end it is better and your system is meant to run it, so I see no reason to have Win7 installed, especially when the system loses some functionality/becomes unstable.

Comment: @LittleHelper you arguments are very weird. Better system? Loses some functionality? What exactly does it lose by not upgrading by crappy 10? Nothing. There are official drivers for win 7 for all of the hardware, not similar, but exact ones.

Comment: Weird arguments? Vague at worst. What you lose by installing Windows 10? The question isn't about that, the question is what you don't gain by not installing it, but that doesn't really matter, it's only my opinion. What operating system you want to use is your preference, but here's the thing: The only operating system that this computer is meant to run is Windows 10. Having successfully installed drivers (that might not even be full drivers, but just plain generic Microsoft drivers) does not mean it magically started supporting that operating system.

Comment: @LittleHelper like I said, they're not generic, they're drivers by hardware providers meant for this specific hardware designed to run on win 7. Besides, did you read, problem is not specific to win 7, it happens on win 10 as well.